# Vector with class array object instantiating

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable

im creating a hash table right now and i have two classes hashtableindex and term. I created a vector array of pointers to term and i cant get past the constructor because im getting an out of range error.I cant use the unordered map in the standard library so i have to create my own.
here is the constructor and private function of hashtableindex:

```
hashtableindex.cpp

#include "hashtableindex.h"
HashTableIndex::HashTableIndex(){
    for(int i=0; i< hash_size; i++){
        hash_vector.push_back(new Term());
    }
}
```

'

```
hashtableindex.h

#include "term.h"
#include <vector>
class HashTableIndex
{

public:
    HashTableIndex();
    ~HashTableIndex();
private:
   vector<Term*> hash_vector;
   const unsigned long hash_size = 1000000;
};
```

and here is the all the code from term

```
term.cpp

#include "term.h"

Term::Term()
{
    name = "";
    next = NULL;
}

Term::~Term()
{

}

Term::Term(string theName)
{
    next = NULL;
    name = theName;
}
```

'

```
term.h
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std

class Term
{
public:
    Term();
    ~Term();
    Term(string name);
    string getName();
    void setName(string name);
private:
    string name;
    Term* next;
```

cant figure out whats wrong but the error comes when i start debugging at the constructor when calling the vector push back any help is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: "I created a vector of term array objects" That is actually an array of pointers to `Term`.

Comment: This should help you figure out the problem: [mcve] If not, then at least it will help you present the problem in a way that others can help you.

Comment: Okay i missed a couple things. the question should be understood now.

Answer (score 2):

Your Term class' constructor is calling itself recursively.

```
Term::Term()
{
    name = "";
    next = new Term(); // recursion here!
    appearances.push_back(new node());
}
```

You should re-think your design to prevent this recursion.

Comment: changed that but that isnt the problem it is throwing a out of range error with the vector after compiling